# I was asked to create a windows service that prints pdf files , the code below works when i run it on a console application but not on the service

Tags: c#, windows, pdf, service, printing

here is my printing code :

```
            //Print & Move the files after printing
            DirectoryInfo sourceinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\fold");
            DirectoryInfo target = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\fold1");
            if (!Directory.Exists(target.FullName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
            }
            foreach (FileInfo fi in sourceinfo.GetFiles())
            {
                if (fi.Length != 0)
                    Pdf.PrintPDFs(fi.FullName);


                fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
                fi.Delete();

            }
```

and here is my pdf class (it uses adobe acrobat reader) :

```
class Pdf
    {
        public static Boolean PrintPDFs(string pdfFileName)
        {
            try
            {
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                proc.StartInfo.Verb = "print";

                //Define location of adobe reader/command line
                //switches to launch adobe in "print" mode
                proc.StartInfo.FileName =
                  @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/p /h {0}", pdfFileName);
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                proc.Start();
                proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                if (proc.HasExited == false)
                {
                    proc.WaitForExit(10000);
                }

                proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

                proc.Close();
                KillAdobe("AcroRd32");
                return true;


            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

        }



    //For whatever reason, sometimes adobe likes to be a stage 5 clinger.
    //So here we kill it with fire.
    private static bool KillAdobe(string name)
    {
        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses().Where(
                     clsProcess => clsProcess.ProcessName.StartsWith(name)))
        {
            clsProcess.Kill();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I think the windows service has a problem accessing the adobe acrobat reader because the code needs to open it to print files.

Comment: share the error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you for your kind replies , I get what you're saying so what can I do to fix this? , my code does 2 specific things : first is to print the file then move that file to another folder , it works perfectly when I run it as a service via a console application (I used Topshelf library , it allows you to run console applications as a service ) but when I install it as a service , It seems to skip the printing part and directly move the file without printing it , I'm sorry if I forgot to mention that , this is my first time posting on this website , I'm still a beginner